# How can I present stored procedure results using ToList method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This is my code:

```
public List<all_Result> Get_Results()
{
    admissionEntities ad = new admissionEntities();
    List<all_Result> Lall_Results = ad.all_Results.ToList();
    return Lall_Results;
}
```

I keep getting an error CS 1061

Comment: where is stored procedure in your question?

Comment: Have a read on [CS1061](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1061) error first. Please update your question to provide [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Thanks.

Comment: Quick run down on c# naming conventions: ClassName, MethodName, PublicProperty, localVariable.. I think you managed to violate every single one :/